# Железнодорожный вокзал

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

База данных "продажа билетов жд вокзала".
Знатоки, подскажите, правильно составлена БД реляционная?
Связи в схеме привязываются по ключам "№ поезда к № поезда" т.е. "один ко многим и многие к одному" но при сохранении пишет поле не может быть NULL

Если БД не правильно составил то, что в ней изменить?
В общем прошу помощи у сообщества.

в Пункты (информация о городе и название страны). Компании (название перевозчика и информация о нем) Билеты (плацкарт или купе и т.д. информация). По остальному и так понятно надеюсь.

P.S. Если можно помогите составить, объясните.

[image: схема БД]

Comment: Проверьте чтобы в полях где по умолчанию стоит NULL он был разрешен (Allow NULL), ключи надеюсь вы задали как AUTO_INCREMENT где по умолчанию не NULL и запрещен NULL?

Comment: @RifmaMan саму БД и логику в ней. я правильно сделал?

Comment: Название таблицы лучше создавать в единственном числе, привязка полей не верна, нужно привязать Поезд->ID Компании к Компания-ID, видимо вы вообще не работали с базами данных и понятия не имеете как с них данные выгребать, связь делают для того, чтобы разбить данные т.е. если у вас Есть поезд и у него компания с ID 20, мы лезем в таблицу с компаниями и от туда уже выгребаем всё об этой компании

Comment: @RifmaMan Да, верно. Не работал. Если есть 5 мин. у Вас... нарисуйте в графическом виде (правильно). я пока учу SQL и сам сервер. Спасибо!

Comment: @RifmaMan 4-5 таблиц главное чтобы верно все. можно проще.

Comment: Странно, что поезда у вас одноразовые, на одну поездку. Иначе, к чему там дата?

Comment: Если возникают какие-либо ошибки (поле не может быть NULL), то лучше подробнее их расписать в вопросе. Правильность субъективна и зависит от задачи — попробуйте ввести данные, написать запросы и посмотреть что получиться, может тогда и возникнет конкретный вопрос. Рекоммендации по улучшению можно давать бесконечно, но они не приблизят Вас к решению задачи.

Comment: Если хотите удалить вопрос, то так и сделайте. Ни к чему его вандализировать

Comment: И заголовок нормальный делать. К чему нам ваш вокзал. Представьте, если каждый будет - вокзал, аэропорт, маламуты...

Comment: Автор, начните с описания сущностей вашей задачи, потом с описания связей между сущностями на обычном языке - потом уже можно приступать к моделированию. По финальной модели рекомендую подсмотреть сюда, очень близко к вашей задаче http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/train_ticketing_systems/index.htm