# Правильно составлена БД?

Tags: java, c#, sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постановка задачи. Разработать систему, обеспечивающую ведение базы данных по поездам, расписанию движения поездов, пассажирах и билетах. База данных должна содержать информацию о времени прибытия и отправки поездов, тип поезда, пунктах отправления и прибытия. Для автоматизации процесса выдачи билета необходимо хранить Ф. И.О. и паспортные данные пассажира, а также размер льгот. Кроме того, в билете указывается номер вагона, номер места, место отправления и место прибытия и дата получения билета. Создать интерфейс, удобный для работы, включающий удобные и понятные формы, отчеты. Организовать работу с таблицами, поиск по ним, формирование и печать отчетов.

использовать C# или Java для разработки GUI

Comment: Постановку задачи необходимо разбить на несколько частей. Каждая часть должна представлять собой только одно действие. Совокупность действий определяет поведение системы, которое должно быть описано. Из вашего описания систему построить невозможно. Заоблачные мечты бывают только в сказках.

Comment: Вы взяли достаточно сложную предметную отрасль для обучения. А "правильно ли" составлена невозможно сказать если нет задания. Это какая-то база, по ней можно строить какие-то запросы, есть какие-то ограничения. Какие запросы нужны по заданию - неясно, вы их себе сами придумали и нам не говорите. Когда озвучите все запросы и ограничения - тогда и можно будет сказать, что в вашей базе не учтено. А пока на вопрос невозможно ответить. Метки вопроса кстати налеплены первые попавшиеся? Зачем здесь метки java и C#? Какая-то специфика разве нужна?

Comment: @Roman C дописал полностью задание

Comment: @ A K  Дополнил описание

Comment: Ну, допустим правильно. Что дальше? Приступайте к разработке, и не забывайте слова от пользователя Roman C

Comment: Извините, но вы не сами делали свою семестровку. Если бы вы сами делали - у вас были бы конкретные вопросы, а у вас только один неконкретный вопрос - "всё ли правильно сделано". Если бы вы сами делали, то понимали бы, почему оказалось то или иное поле на той или иной таблице. Вот почему у вас тип поезда оказался на таблице поезда или на таблице расписания? Почему взялось поле номер вагона, если его не было в задании. Вы же даже не читали задание - не знаете, что у вас поля код пассажира не было в задании. И зачем вы убрали существенные подробности задания? То слишком много пишете, то мало.

Comment: И ещё.У вас уже был [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823284/213987), зачем вы создаёте дубликаты?

Comment: И если не секрет, почему у вас такие разные скриншоты? Вы делаете это в разных программах? Как называется программа, в которой вы делали скриншот из предыдущего вопроса? А из этого? И почему на этом скриншоте у вас есть какие-то странные значки типа восьмёрки (вы наверное знаете, что это означает и как вы их сумели сделать), а почему на предыдущем их нет? Также (ведь вы сами это всё делали) вы наверное знаете, зачем на этом скриншоте подписывали маленькую букву "т" к каждой таблице и почему на прошлом скриншоте таких буковок не было.

Comment: Если хотите удалить вопрос, то так и сделайте. Ни к чему его вандализировать

Answer (score 5):

Я бы подправил Вашу схему исходя из реалий жизни и полезности все называть своими именами по-максимуму следующим образом:
Поезд у Вас, скорее всего, не поезд, а рейс (или поездка). У рейса есть дата, кроме времени. Билет у пассажира именно на конкретную дату. Рейс связан с физическим поездом, бригадой и т.п. (на перспективу).
Избегайте экономии на разнообразии объектов. Легче позже избавиться от лишних путем объединения, чем добавлять и разделять в процессе написания кода.
Расписание - тоже связано с поездкой.
Если речь идет не только о планировании, а о реальном режиме времени, то и у пассижира, и у рейса, и у тем более поезда, есть текущие статусы (состояния) и их история. Сел пассажир или опоздал, подан поезд на посадку или еще нет, и так далее.
Билет связан с местом. Но билет, исходя из схемы, еще может быть не продан, т.е. не существовать, не иметь кода пассажира и т.п.- Места можно классифицировать, начиная с классификации вагонов (купе, плацкарт, бронепоезд...). 
Соответственно, места - боковое, верхнее и т.п. Плюс может оказаться для сортировки полезными, например, флаги "рядом с туалетом". Для конкретных мест в "физических" вагонах могут быть быть актуальными пометки типа "поломано".

В общем, фантазия вам в помощь.